# Custom param decorator with Swagger documentation

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

In Nestjs you can use `@Query() query: MyDto` to automatically validate your query params, and to generate a Swagger documentation.

I've created a custom decorator, that kinda replaces the `@Query` decorator. My custom decorator does a few things differently.

BUT, I can't find a way to generate the Swagger documentation automatically, for example:

**Using `@Query`:
[Swagger screenshot with param documented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGXUa.png)**

Controller:

```
@Get()
  findAll(@Query() query: AqpDto, @Tenant() tenantId: string) {
    return this.logsService.findAll(query, tenantId);
  }
```

**Using my decorator:
[Swagger screenshot without params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVHcD.png)**

```
@Get()
  findAll(@Aqp() query: AqpDto, @Tenant() tenantId: string) {
    return this.logsService.findAll(query, tenantId);
  }
```

I consume these APIs using `swagger-client` so the lack of the query param definitions is not only missing documentation, but also breaks the API call, as `swagger-client` doesn't send the params as expected.

I've tried `applyDecorators`, I tried to find ways to automatically execute the `Query` once my decorator is called, I tried to find the source code of `Query` to identify how it adds the `Dto` params to Swagger. I don't know what else to do do.

I'm trying to find a clean solution, but no luck so far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Query()` related code can be found in the `@nestjs/common` package, in the `route-params.decorator.ts` file.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/decorators/http/route-params.decorator.ts#L411

It doesn't do anything with Swagger, and it shouldn't, that's not its responsibility.

```
export function Query(
  property?: string | (Type<PipeTransform> | PipeTransform),
  ...pipes: (Type<PipeTransform> | PipeTransform)[]
): ParameterDecorator {
  return createPipesRouteParamDecorator(RouteParamtypes.QUERY)(
    property,
    ...pipes,
  );
}
```

The `@Body()`, `@Query()`, `@Param()`...etc. decorators all have a very similar implementation. They all call the `createPipesRouteParamDecorator(...)` function with a `RouteParamtypes` value.

```
export enum RouteParamtypes {
  BODY,
  QUERY,
  PARAM,
  ...
}
```

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/enums/route-paramtypes.enum.ts

In the end it uses `Reflect.defineMetadata(...)` to set metadata on the controller about the query, body, param...etc.

The `@nestjs/swagger` packages uses the constants under which this metadata is saved and gathers this metadata (using `Reflect.getMetadata()`).

For example:

https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/services/parameter-metadata-accessor.ts

Based on the gathered metadata its able to construct the Swagger documentation. You can tweak this by adding extra decorators provided by the `@nestjs/swagger` package. With these you can provide extra metadata that is gathered to help generate the Swagger documenation. In your case you can use the `@ApiQuery()` decorator to provide extra hints.

```
@ApiQuery({ 
  name: 'query', 
  schema: { .... },
  type: AqpDto,
  required: true
})
@Get()
findAll(@Aqp() query: AqpDto, @Tenant() tenantId: string) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Christophe. Thanks for such comprehensive response. It makes a lot of sense. It's much more clear how it works. I remember see the "Reflect" call somewhere but I didn't understand what it was doing.

With the @ApiQuery decorator, indeed it works like a charm. I'm afraid using Reflect myself and setting the metadata myself on my own decorator may be above my knowledge of Nest/TS/JS. I'll look at the codebase and do some extra research and give it try. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Here simple code sample how to add query parameter to swagger documentation in custom decorator:

```js
import { ExecutionContext, createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DECORATORS } from '@nestjs/swagger/dist/constants'

export const YourDecorator = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // Here some decorator logic:
    return parseInt(request.query.id) + 1
  },
  [
    (target, key, index) => {
      // Here we will define query parameter for swagger documentation
      const explicit = Reflect.getMetadata(DECORATORS.API_PARAMETERS, target[key]) ?? []
      Reflect.defineMetadata(DECORATORS.API_PARAMETERS, [
        ...explicit,
        {
          description: 'Custom id field',
          in: 'query',
          name: 'id',
          required: true,
          type: 'integer'
        }
      ], target[key]);
    }
  ]
);
```

In controller class:

```js
@Get('yourmethod')
async yourMethod(@YourDecorator() id: number):  Promise<number> {
    return id
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It works but is not generic, because the parameter name is hardcoded, there is a way using Reflection to get the parameter name dynamically?